# IPad Simple Form with Flexible Space

Tags: iphone, ipad, layout, formatting

Im creating an app for an internal process where our trainers will go out to clients and fill in a survey of the customer after the fact.

I want to create a flexible space with in the view. Example if they click a checkbox that the Customer is not happy than text fields will be shown to enter more information which will need to dynamically push all fields under it down to accomodate the new fields. If the user is happy no fields need to appear and no dynamic shifting is necessary.

Just wondering if anyone has done this before and if there is a clean way to execute it.

Comment: I just want to make it clear though that iphone do not have any checkbox in it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a control that will do this.

But it should not be that hard. This code is not tested but something like this

```
//views needs to be ordered in the subview list by y position
//can be in in uibuilder or on awakefrom nib..

-(void) addTextFieldAfterView:(UIView*) selectedView
{
  CGRect f = CGRectMake(selectedView.origin.x,
                        selectedView.origin.y+5+selectedView.size.height,
                        selectedView.size.width,
                        150);

  UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:f];
  [self insertSubview:tf belowSubview:selectedView];
  int start = [self.subviews indexOfObject:tf];

  //move everything down
  for(int i =start; i < [self.subviews count];i++)
  {
    UIView* v = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    v.frame = CGRectMake(v.origin.x,
                        v.origin.y+150,
                        v.size.width,
                        v.size.height);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using UITableView for forms.  This is what a lot of the forms in the Settings app uses.  It's fairly simple to turn sections on and off -- just respond to the messages with the right number of sections and then fill them in as requested.

Comment: So do you just create custom cells for each record in the table/form?